# mplayer - custom fps

Tags: frame-rate, mplayer

I need to set custom output fps in mplayer but I can't use -fps option because it just changes video duration time. I need to change fps with keeping video duration time (i.e skip or add some frames). Is there such option in mplayer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the scaletemp filter. This filter will  not interpolate the movie (afaik).

```
mplayer -af scaletempo -speed 2.0 movie.mkv
```